# Thumb rule for when an exception should be advertised and when should it be handled

Tags: java, exception

I have method `x` that calls another method inside it called `y` which throws an exception `MyException`. At this time I have 2 options, either to advertise my method `x` with the exception `MyException` ... like

```
public void x() throws MyException {
// call to y
}
```

(since `y` is advertised with `throws` clause like this...)

```
public void y() throws MyException {
// code
}
```

or wrap the call to `y` in my method `x` in try catch block and handle it ? like this..

```
public void x() {
 try {
   // call to y
 } catch (MyException e) {
   // handle exception
 } 
}
```

what is the thumb rule ?

Answer (score 1):

If your method can keep the contract with its callers, regardless of the exception, then the exception is something it can, and probably should, handle.

If a caller would be confused to find out they said "do x", and there was an internal problem with the "y" part of doing "x", because "x" didn't really get done, then you should expose the exception (or some other exception which has a `MyException` as the cause).

And - consider if the caller can reasonably handle the exception, or if there's any reason for the program to continue, and if the answer is no to either, consider using a `RuntimeException` or `Error`, respectively.

That's what I'd say, anyway.

Comment: Edited to include what I claim about `RuntimeException`s and `Error`s.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple:

If you can deal with the inner exception, you should catch it and do something reasonable

If you can *not* deal with it, you have two choices:

1. If the exception is *implementation specific*, catch it and throw an exception acceptable to your caller (typically wrapping the actual exception)
2. If the exception is in your caller's domain, declare as throwing it and let *your* caller deal with it

Here are some examples of each type:

#### Example 1: Dealing with it:

```
public void deleteFile(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try {
        file.delete();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // No big deal - it was already deleted
    }
}
```

#### Example 2: Wrapping it:

```
public void changePassword(String username, String password) throws UserUpdateException {
    try {
        // execute SQL to update the password
        // but storing the user in a DB is an imlementation choice
        // we could use a file on disk or a remote web service to store user info
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new UserUpdateException(e);
    }
}
```

#### Example 3: Doing nothing:

```
public void insertIntoDatabase(Record record) throws SQLException {
    // execute SQL on the database
    // using a DB is implied - let the exception bubble up
}
```